# It is possible to get a closed-form for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{n})}{n^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request, definite-integrals, trigonometric-series

I think that will not be useful to compute the **Apéry's constant** as 
$$\zeta(3)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\sin^2(3x)dx+\frac{1}{3\pi}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{n})}{n^2}\right),$$
which is easily deduced from 
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\sin^2(3x)dx=\frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{3\pi}{n}-\sin(\frac{3\pi}{n})\right).$$

For deduce this last identity I've used an online tool of symbolic calculus. I say that couldn't be useful since neither I don't know how evaluate an alternative of the series of integrals $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2n}}\sin^2(3x)dx$ (if it is feasible, to compute in a distinct form).

In any case I would like to know

> **Question.** It is know, or it is possible to get a closed-form for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{3\pi}{n})}{n^2}$$ in terms of known constants? **Thanks in advance.**

When I've do more computations, using some trigonometric tricks I've found also with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n^2}$ and  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})}{n^2}$. It is easy to check the absolute convergence of such series, thus by **comparision test** these series are convergents. Using another time **Wolfram Alpha (its Online Series Calculator)** I don't to get a closed-form (only an approximation is given for such series) in terms of known constant, this is as exact value. Are know these series? When I've used this computation in **its (General) Calculator**, yes  then I've obtained some closed-form, but the *Series Calculator* doesn't sure any closed-form.

My attemps were using **partial summation** and **Euler-MacLaurin (first approximation)**, but I believe that I can not find this real value with these methods.

Comment: I recoignize that the identity involving previous constant is vague, but now I am interesting in if it is possible obtain a closed form for previous cited series and how obtain it. Thank.s

Comment: Since $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,$ this is equivalent to asking for the general closed form of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sqrt[n]a}{n^2}.$

Comment: Very thanks much @Lucian feel free to update or ask in future season if you can improve my question.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to consider: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{sin^2(\alpha\cdot n)}{n^2\cdot\alpha}=\frac{\pi-\alpha}{2}$

Comment: Many thanks @gabrielecassese I am going to think in it.

Comment: I get $-0.046998999668291721739\dots$ for the series in question, which is very close to a rational number $-0.047$ though it's probably just a coincidence

Comment: Many thanks for your attention and always for your excellent feedback @YuriyS

Comment: Could you clarify this part: "When I've used this computation in its (General) Calculator, yes then I've obtained some closed-form" - what kind of closed form did you obtain and how?

Comment: I don't remember it, I think that should be the approximations that provide Wolfram Alpha online calculator as possible closed-forms @YuriyS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't expect a closed form, however we can find an integral form for the series involving [Kelvin functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_functions):

> $$f(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin \left( \frac{a}{n} \right)}{n^2}=-\frac{1}{2a^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\text{ber}_1 ( \sqrt{2}~u)+\text{bei}_1 (\sqrt{2}~u) }{e^{\frac{1}{2a}u^2}-1} u^2 du \tag{1}$$

Where the Kelvin functions can be defined as real and imaginary parts of a certain Bessel function:

$$\text{ber}_1 (\sqrt{2}~u)=\Re J_1 \left((i-1)u \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{u \sin t} \cos \left(t+u \sin t \right) dt$$

$$\text{bei}_1 (\sqrt{2}~u)=\Im J_1 \left((i-1)u \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{u \sin t} \sin \left(t+u \sin t \right) dt$$

---

The form is derived by directly using the Taylor series for $\sin$ and reversing order of summation:

$$f(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k a^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)! n^{2k+3}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k a^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \zeta (2k+3)$$

Now we use the integral form of the zeta function:

$$\zeta (2k+3)=\frac{1}{(2k+2)!} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{2k+2}}{e^x-1}dx$$

So:

$$f(a)=\frac{a}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2dx}{e^x-1} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (ax)^{2k}}{(2k+1)!^2 (k+1)}$$

The sum in terms of Kelvin functions was found by Wolfram Alpha. Then after some changes of variable in the integral, we get the form (1).

Comment: Many thanks I accept the answer and reasoning, since I was asking if is it possible to get a closed-form. On the other hand your formulas have a great mathematical beauty, many thanks I am going to study it in detail.